# Do I need to exclude "node_modules" in tsconfig-json?

Tags: typescript

Many `tsconfig-json` examples have `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` setting.

I always frown upon this setting. I feel TypeScript would be pretty dumb if I need to tell it explicitly  that don't transpile the codes in `node_modules`(because that is not my code)! But on the other hand, I search https://www.typescriptlang.org/ and I can't find any information about whether I should exclude "node_modules" or not.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude says "Specifies an array of filenames or patterns that should be skipped when resolving include." So this seems to indicate I don't need to because my src folder doesn't include node_modules.

Comment: exclude it if you don't want your app to be slower than the falling velocity of sakura flowers 5cm/s

Comment: You're right, it's not necessary, but at the same time I think you should keep it in case you do need to ignore other files. Then you can't forget to exclude node_modules. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `include` directive with just the `src` directory, you need not have `exclude: ['node_modules']`.
If your tsconfig file included files outside src, say you have the `tests/` directory outside the `src` which you need to be included by tsconfig, you would have to include the root directory in the `includes` list.
In such cases, if you have an include for everything in the root directory, and if you also have got some specific excludes like `exclude: [.prettier.js]`, you need to explicitly exclude node_modules too.

TLDR:

Explicit exclude of `node_modules` would be required in situation where you are including everything in the project's root folder in the tsconfig , and also excluding some specific files/folders.